# How to create download link in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, download

I am having problem creating a download link to download files via a Mobile App from Laravel Storage folder.

I did something like `$link = Response::Download(storage_path()./file/example.png)` but to no avail.

I moved the file to the public folder and used `http://domain.com/file/example.png` and `asset('file/example.png')` but to no avail.

I am getting `404 NOT FOUND ERROR`

How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you want to link directly to the actual file (in public folder) or do you want a route/controller action that forces a download?

Comment: A route/controller will do, bro

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Take a look at the Laravel Helpers documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers

If you want a link to your asset, you can do it like this:

```
$download_link = link_to_asset('file/example.png');
```

---

**Edit**

If the above method does not work for you, then you can implement a fairly simple Download route in **app/routes.php** which looks like this:

*Note this example assumes your files are located in **app/storage/file/** location*

```
// Download Route
Route::get('download/{filename}', function($filename)
{
    // Check if file exists in app/storage/file folder
    $file_path = storage_path() .'/file/'. $filename;
    if (file_exists($file_path))
    {
        // Send Download
        return Response::download($file_path, $filename, [
            'Content-Length: '. filesize($file_path)
        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
        exit('Requested file does not exist on our server!');
    }
})
->where('filename', '[A-Za-z0-9\-\_\.]+');
```

Usage: http://your-domain.com/download/example.png

This will look for a file in: app/storage/file/example.png (if it exists, send the file to browser/client, else it will show error message).

P.S. `'[A-Za-z0-9\-\_\.]+` this regular expression ensures user can only request files with name containing  `A-Z` or `a-z` (letters), `0-9` (numbers), `-` or `_` or `.` (symbols). Everything else is discarded/ignored. This is a safety / security measure....

Comment: @Latheesan: thanks it work for me aslo, just i had to enable `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` in `php.ini` file.

Comment: I have a file in storage/app/public folder. My link is following
 <a href="{{ asset('/1489082996.docx') }}"> Read Paper</a> . But when i click the link it says "not found execption"

Answer (score 14):

Updating answer for Laravel 5.0 and above:

```
<a href={{ asset('file/thing.png') }}>Thing</a>
```

Comment: I have a file in storage/app/public folder. My link is following
 <a href="{{ asset('/1489082996.docx') }}"> Read Paper</a> . But when i click the link it says "not found execption"

Comment: Hi @MutasimFuad the `storage` directory is not used for public assets, it's actually for internal storage like your logs.  The directory you should host your public assets is in `/public/` which is in the root of your project.

Comment: Hi, @DylanPierce! if i wish the files to be opened only by those who are logged in in my application, should I use /public/ too? (I have middleware authentication already)

Comment: @SergejFomin no, public is going to public to the web no matter what. You should use a combination of the Laravel filesystem and a custom route to verify that the user has authorization to the resource, then use the filesystem to find it in `/storage` and send it to the user. Any resource in public is open to the entire web.

Comment: Better solution than giving download option.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any route or controller.Just give it to `anchor` tag.

```
 <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}/file/example.png" target="_blank">
     <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download File</button>
 </a>
```